# Unknown error from inserting data into database (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have not seen this error before, I tried inserting these to my database table

```
INSERT courses 
SET startTime= '30-Dec-2020 09:00:00', exam_catID = 2, courseTitle = 'Test course',  
courseCode = 'Tcs299', duration = 3
```

**courses Atributes**

- startTime (Varchar)
- exam_catID (Int)
- courseTitle (Varchar)
- courseCode (Varchar)
- duration (int)

**Outpur Error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface::escapeString() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Tracker.php on line 149 and defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php:2991 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Tracker.php(149): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->escapeString(NULL) #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Tracker.php(841): PhpMyAdmin\Tracker::isTracked('time_table_syst...', NULL) #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php(345): PhpMyAdmin\Tracker::handleQuery('INSERT courses ...') #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(958): PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->tryQuery('INSERT courses ...', 256, 1) #4 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(1177): PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndMeasureTime('INSERT courses ...') #5 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Sql.php(2225): PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeTheQuery(Array, 'INSERT courses ...', false, 'time_table_syst in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line 2991
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use proper `insert` statement. You are missing `INTO` clause:

```
INSERT into courses
SET startTime= '30-Dec-2020 09:00:00', exam_catID = 2, courseTitle = 'Test course',  
courseCode = 'Tcs299', duration = 3
```

Or you can use the standard sql as follows:

```
INSERT into courses( startTime, exam_catID , courseTitle,  courseCode, duration) 
values ( '30-Dec-2020 09:00:00', 2, 'Test course', 'Tcs299', 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the cause of the error. I missed out *INTO* after the *INSERT* ,            
                                                                                                                                  
         *INSERT INTO courses 
SET startTime= '30-Dec-2020 09:00:00', exam_catID = 2, courseTitle = 'Test course',  
courseCode = 'Tcs299', duration = 3*

Comment: You should always use standard sql. Anyway, it solved your problem. Good.

Comment: MySQL supports this syntax.

Comment: Updated the answer with mysql and standard sql @GordonLinoff